# Adding a search form using a DateTime template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my EditorTemplates, I have DateTime.cshtml - which works find in create/edit/update views:

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime> 

@if ( Model.HasValue ) { 
   @Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" , Model.Value ) , new  { @class = "datepicker span2" } ) 
} 
else { 
   @Html.TextBox( "" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" , DateTime.Now ) , new { @class = "datepicker span2" } ) 
}
```

When creating a search view, I also want to use a datetime picker - how would I code the view use the code above, when it's not linked to a model, but just plain HTML?

If I just enter the following into my Razor markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Availability between: @Html.TextBox( "From" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") , new  { @class = "datepicker span2" } ) 
                         and: @Html.TextBox( "To" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") , new  { @class = "datepicker span2" } )
        <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
}
```

I just get the error:

```
{"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."}
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `TextBox` inside your main view. If you want your custom editor template to render you should use the `EditorFor` helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Availability between: 
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.From)
        and: 
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.To)

        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

If the `From` and `To` properties are of type `DateTime`, then ASP.NET MVC will wutomatically render your custom editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml`).

Comment: Hi @Darin-Dimitrov - the From and To aren't properties of the Room model (to which the above view form is attached, within the Rooms controller), but instead properties of a linked table to the Room model - however these are only linked within the controller, so I'm not certain where to declare From/To for them to be picked up as DateTime.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. You should have a view model passed to your views containing those properties. An ASP.NET MVC view shouldn't know things about EF models, tables, linked tables and stuff. An ASP.NET MVC view manipulates a **view model** which is a class that you specifically define for the requirements of the view. But if those datetimes are inside some complex propery of your model you could always specify it in the lambda expression: `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProperty.To)`.

Comment: ViewModel is what I was looking for (I've been hung up on Models only being connected to database tables) - knew I'd seen something connected to this before... Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a `DateTime` in the `String.Format` - that is why you are getting that error, it expects one parameter, but you haven't supplied any.  Try using `DateTime.Now`

e.g.

```
@Html.TextBox( "From" , String.Format( "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now ), 
new  { @class = "datepicker span2" } )
```

Alternatively, just add two `DateTime` properties to your ViewModel, and use the `EditorFor` helper on them.