# Showing a list of results under a search form, which uses a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

following on from an earlier post: [Adding a search form using a DateTime template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285375/adding-a-search-form-using-a-datetime-template/11288466?iemail=1#11288466)

I also tried following the Search example here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

...but that doesn't make use of a ViewModel as suggested in the answer to my previous post.

I am trying to help with a search from, which will take two dates (from/to), based on a ViewModel of:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

My Views/Search/Index.cshtml is:

```
@model ttp.Models.SearchViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search Availability";
}
<h2>Search Availability</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.From)</div>
        <div class="span2">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.From)</div>
        <div class="span2">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.From)</div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.To)</div>
        <div class="span2">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.To)</div>
        <div class="span2">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.To)</div>
    </div>

     <div class="row">
        <div class="span2 offset2"><button type="submit">Search</button></div>
     </div>
}
```

The Get: /Search/Index controller is:

```
    //
    // GET: /Search/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SearchViewModel svm = new SearchViewModel();
        svm.From = DateTime.Today;
        svm.To = DateTime.Today;
        return View(svm);
    }
```

So far so good - my view shows the textboxes with the dates defaulting to today (using a DateTime Helper).  When I click Search, the code goes to the SearchController // Post: / Search as follows:

```
    //
    // Post: /Search/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchViewModel searchViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Not valid, so just return the search boxes again
            return View(searchViewModel);
        }

        // Get the From/To of the searchViewModel

        DateTime dteFrom = searchViewModel.From;
        DateTime dteto = searchViewModel.To;

        // Query the database using the posted from/to dates

        IQueryable<Room> rooms = db.Rooms.Where(r => r.Clients.Any(c => c.Departure >= dteFrom && c.Departure < dteTo));

        // This is where I'm unsure

        ViewBag.Rooms = rooms.ToList();
        return View(rooms.ToList());

        }
```

Where I'm at now unsure is the last couple of lines of the Post controller - how do I return the list of rooms in IQueryable rooms - and show the list of rooms on the screen?  Do I redirect to another View (if so, how do I pass the list of rooms to that view)?  If I just try and run the code above, I get the error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ttp.Models.Room]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ttp.Models.SearchViewModel'.
```

Am I trying to mix apples and pears - is there anyway of showing the list of rooms under the From and To search box (ViewModel)?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could return a different view that will contain the search results:

```
IQueryable<Room> rooms = db.Rooms.Where(r => r.Clients.Any(c => c.Departure >= dteFrom && c.Departure < dteTo));
return View("Result", rooms.ToList());
```

And inside `Result.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Room>
... show the rooms here
```

If you want to stay no the same view, modify your view model so that it contains a third property which will represent the search results (a collection of rooms) that you will populate inside your POST controller action and redisplay the same view:

```
IQueryable<Room> rooms = db.Rooms.Where(r => r.Clients.Any(c => c.Departure >= dteFrom && c.Departure < dteTo));
searchViewModel.Rooms = rooms;
return View(searchViewModel);
```

and then inside the view you could have a section to display the results:

```
@if (Model.Rooms != null)
{
    ... display the search results here
}
```

But in both cases I guess that the `Room` object is a domain model. Good practice dictates that you should define a view model in which you include only the information that your view needs:

```
public class RoomViewModel
{
    ... only properties that you need to work with on the view
}
```

and then have an `IEnumerable<RoomViewModel> Rooms { get; set; }` property to work with. You could still fetch your `IQueryable<Room>` domain model in the controller action from your DAL layer, but before passing it to the view make sure to perform the conversion to the view model. It is where [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could come in handy.

Comment: Either you have a TURIN computer posting for you, or you are amazingly prolific in helping people here - either/or, I am grateful - it's helping me, and more specifically, the people I'm trying to help in this community centre, an awful lot!  I pass on their thanks too.  Cheers!

Comment: Is there any way I can keep the search form at the top of the results.cshtml - or is that into the area of PartialViews?

Comment: Yes, you can, that's what the second part of my answer covers => add a property to your existing view model that will contain a collection of rooms and inside the view test whether this property is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning different models to the same view, so for a start just change your controller to return the passed in `searchViewModel`.

```
ViewBag.Rooms = rooms.ToList();
return View(searchViewModel);
```

You can also return the list of rooms to the same view, as you have done with the ViewBag, you just don't have anywhere in the view that is rendering any markup for the list:

```
@model ttp.Models.SearchViewModel 
@{     
    ViewBag.Title = "Search Availability"; 
} 
<h2>Search Availability</h2> 
@using (Html.BeginForm())  
{      
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.From)</div>
        <div class="span2">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.From)</div>
        <div class="span2">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.From)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">@Html.LabelFor(x => x.To)</div>
        <div class="span2">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.To)</div>
        <div class="span2">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.To)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2 offset2"><button type="submit">Search</button></div>
    </div> 
}
@if (ViewBag.Rooms != null)
{
    foreach (var room in ViewBag.Rooms as List<Room>)
    {
        // Build your room list markup here
    }
}
```